# object is not a function in mysql db using with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm following the [tutorial](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2596) but first i got this error:

```
deprecated: connect() is now done automatically
```

I changed my code but after that im faceing this error:

```
object is not a function at Client.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native)
```

and I've no idea as I'm new to nodejs and mysql so kindly help me out!!

here is my code:

```
var Client = require('mysql').createClient({'host':'localhost','port':'3306','user':'root', 'password':''});
var client = new Client();

console.log('Connecting to mysql..');
ClientConnectionReady(client);

 ClientConnectionReady = function(client){
     client.query('USE login',function(err,result){
     if(err){
          console.log('cant create Table Error:'+ err.message);
      client.end();
      return;
 }
 ClientReady(client);
};
```

---

```
ClientReady = function(client){
    var values = ['fahad','tariq'];
    client.query('INSERT into Login SET username = ?, password = ?',values,
    function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log("ClientReady Error:" + error.message);
            client.end();
            return;
        }
        console.log('inserted:'+result.affectedRows+'ros.');
        console.log('Id inserted:'+ result.insertId);
    });
    GetData(client);
}
```

---

```
GetData = function(client){
    client.query(
        'SELECT * FROM Login',
            function selectCb(err,result,fields){
                if(err) {
                    console.log('Getdata Error'+err.message);
                    client.end();
                    return;
                }
                if(result.length>0) {
                    var firstResult = results[0];
                    console.log('username' + firstResult['username']);
                    console.log('password'+firstResult['password']);
                }
            });
    client.end();
    console.log('connection closed');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what's causing your specific message, but in `ClientReady` you're calling `GetData` before your `INSERT` has had a chance to execute; you should be doing it *inside* the callback from the `INSERT`.

UPDATE: Now that someone was kind enough to properly indent everything (hint: stuff that should be indented should *begin* with 4 spaces) it becomes clear that you have a similar problem in `GetData()`: you're calling `client.end()` before your callback has had a chance to execute. Thus your `SELECT` callback is trying to use a closed MySQL connection, which is probably causing the failure.